# Swift TableView ImageView + Label = Fatal Error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a tableview to show a Project's title including the image. 
I'm using FirebaseStorage and FirebaseDatabase.

The Problem is, that when I have only **one** protect, I get "Fatal error: Index out of range", as soon as I click on the Title.
When I have more than one Project you can see what happens in the video.

Maybe someone can help me, since something isn't right with the index handling. :)

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import Foundation
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController  {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addProject: UIButton!


    var posts = [Post]()



    var textToBeSent: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserService.posts(for: User.current) { (posts) in
            self.posts = posts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        Utilities.addShadowtoButton(addProject)

    }

    func configureTableView() {
        // remove separators for empty cells
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        // remove separators from cells
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toDetails" {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! ShowProjectDetailsViewController
            destVC.post = sender as? Post
        }
    }

}
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
             public subscript(safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
               return (startIndex <= index && index < endIndex) ? self[index] : nil
             }
          }

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: post)

    }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 2
  }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let post = posts[indexPath.section]

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostImageCell") as! PostImageCell
            let imageURL = URL(string: post.imageURL)
            cell.postImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL)

            return cell

        case 1:

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostSubCell") as! PostSubCell
            cell.projectName.text = post.projectTitle

            return cell


        default:
            fatalError("Error: unexpected indexPath.")
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:

           let post = posts[indexPath.section]
           return post.imageHeight

        case 1:

       return PostSubCell.height

        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    }
```

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth.FIRUser
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseUI
import FirebaseAuth


struct UserService {

         static func posts(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {

            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user.uid)

            ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
               guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
                   return completion([])
            }

            let posts = snapshot.reversed().compactMap(Post.init)
            completion(posts)
        })
    }

}
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase.FIRDataSnapshot

class Post {

//      Next let's add properties to store all the additional information we need. Add the following to your post class.
    var key: String?

       let imageURL: String
       let imageHeight: CGFloat
       let creationDate: Date
       let imageName: String
       let projectTitle: String
       let projectLocation: String
       let projectDescription: String
       let projectBeginn: String
       let projectEnd: String


//    You'll get some compiler errors for not having any initializers or default values for certain properties. Let's go ahead and fix that:

    init(imageURL: String, imageName: String, imageHeight: CGFloat, projectTitle: String, projectLocation: String, projectDescription: String, projectBeginn: String, projectEnd: String) {
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.imageHeight = imageHeight
        self.creationDate = Date()
        self.projectTitle = projectTitle
        self.projectLocation = projectLocation
        self.projectDescription = projectDescription
        self.projectBeginn = projectBeginn
        self.projectEnd = projectEnd
    }

    var dictValue: [String : Any] {
        let createdAgo = creationDate.timeIntervalSince1970

        return ["image_url" : imageURL,
                "image_name" : imageName,
                "image_height" : imageHeight,
                "created_at" : createdAgo,
                "projectTitle" : projectTitle,
                "projectLocation" : projectLocation,
                "projectDescription" : projectDescription,
                "projectBeginn" : projectBeginn,
                "projectEnd": projectEnd ]

    }
    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any],
            let imageURL = dict["image_url"] as? String,
            let imageName = dict["image_name"] as? String,
            let imageHeight = dict["image_height"] as? CGFloat,
            let createdAgo = dict["created_at"] as? TimeInterval,
            let projectTitle = dict["projectTitle"] as? String,
            let projectLocation = dict["projectLocation"] as? String,
            let projectDescription = dict["projectDescription"] as? String,
            let projectBeginn = dict["projectBeginn"] as? String,
            let projectEnd = dict["projectEnd"] as? String




            else { return nil }

        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.imageHeight = imageHeight
        self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: createdAgo)
        self.projectTitle = projectTitle
        self.projectLocation = projectLocation
        self.projectDescription = projectDescription
        self.projectBeginn = projectBeginn
        self.projectEnd = projectEnd

       }
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your `didSelect` you are using `indexPath.row` but you have one section per post so I think you should be using `indexPath.section`

Comment: The layout is shows properly as you need in your project, by using above code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your `numberOfSection` by `[Post]`. And also you assigning `performSegue` on click of `indexPath.row`. So it's throws an error, you've to use `indexPath.section` instead of `indexPath.row` in `didSelectItem()` method

e.g.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)   
 {
     let post = posts[indexPath.section] // Use here section instead of row
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: post)

 }
```

Comment: WelCome Happy coading :)